# copy data from one database to another in mssql while maintaining consistency

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We need to push data from one database A to database B while maintaining consistency in current transactions happening in database B.

Problem:Data cannot be pushed directly to tables in database B because the customers might see inconsistent data,since it is join of 3-4 tables.

Approach:We have tried to create loading tables and loaded tables.We have created one synonym to point to loaded tables.Data will be pushed to loading tables first and once all data is pushed,we will copy that data to loaded tables and at that time synonym will be pointed to loading tables.Once all the data is copied to loaded tables,synonym will again point to loaded tables.
The problem with this approach is while switching synonym we need to drop synonym ad create same pointing to other(loading or loaded) table and at that time any incoming transaction might fail,if it could not find synonym.
Is there any other way to to cater this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you might be using NOLOCK in your queries? Otherwise the users would not see any inconsistencies while data is being loaded.

Comment: @Sean No,lets suppose data is updated for one table A and for table B it is not yet copied and lets suppose user is doing join on these two tables,then he will get inconsistent data.

Comment: OK. Then perhaps you should put your data migration into a transaction. That way the user can't see the new data in TableA until the transaction is finalized. The biggest challenge here is that we don't have a lot of details about what you are trying to do and guessing blind.

Comment: @SeanLange- We are usin azure data factory to push data from one database to another,that will not provide transactional level push.The problem statement is that I need to push data everyday from some set of tables from database A to database B and while pushing if there are any incoming transactions which are referring those tables on database B ,how that can be handled,I was also thinking of table swap but that also will have downtime.

Comment: So you have to push a lot of data from one database to another on a regular basis. And you must keep your data 100% accurate at all times with zero downtime or possibility of error. Does that sound like what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SeanLange-Yes exactly the same

Comment: Something on that list of requirements has to give. You can't accomplish all aspects of your requirements. The easiest would be to find a maintenance window and do your data movements in that timeframe. Either tell the users the data might be inconsistent, or set the database to single user preventing any queries until you are done.